# Longtable spacing

Tags: tables, spacing, longtable

I am using longtable and I cannot find a way to adjust its column spacing.
I want a table like this:

[image]

But I am getting this:

[image]

This is what I am doing for defining table size:

```
 \begin{longtable}{p{.1\textwidth} p{.2\textwidth} p{.2\textwidth}p{.3\textwidth}}
    xxxxx & xxxxx & xxx & xxxxx\\
    \end{longtable}
```

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid I don't understand the question. The second image seems to include 3 tables? Which one is the one you want to look like the first image? Could you please give us a small compilable document which produces a table with the layout you get now and explain exactly what changes you would like to implement?

Comment: Just look at the serial numbers, you will understand. I am using longtable for a table over multiple pages. I want to reduce the spacing between columns.

Comment: The first three columns should be `l` and the last column wants to be p{some wider value}

Comment: @DavidCarlisle may be the 2 nd column is also `p{length}`

Comment: @touhami looks like a single compound word, so if you wanted to allow breaking, would need url package or similar to allow breaking on `_`

Answer (score 3):

Package `ltxtable` allows the combination of `longtable` with `tabularx` column type `X`. The latter is useful for the last column with the description text. The first columns can be set via column type `l`.
The indentation in the description part can be achieved via `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` (assuming there is only one paragraph).

Since the package `ltxtable` requires a separate file for the table, package `filecontents` is used, which allows the environment `filecontents` inside the document body. Also the file is overwritten each time and is therefore uptodate.

The larger line spacing between rows is achieved by redefining `\arraystretch`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{6}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-table-parameters}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{longtable}{lll>{\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1 }X}
\caption{Some parameters}\\
\toprule
\# & Name & Type & Description \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{(continued)}\\
\toprule
\# & Name & Type & Description \\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
f1 & duration & Integer
  & Duration of the connection\\
f2 & protocol\_type & Nominal
  & Protocol type of the connection: TCP, UDP, ICMP\\
f3 & service & Nominal
  & http, ftp, smtp, telnet, \dots\ and others\\
f4 & flag & Nominal
  & Connection status: SF, S0, S1, S2, S3, OTH, REJ, RSTO, RSTOS0, SH,
  RSTRH, SHR\\
f5 & src\_bytes & Integer
  & Bytes sent in one connection\\
f6 & dst\_bytes & Integer
  & Bytes received in one connection\\
f7 & land & Binary
  & If source and destination IP addresses and port numbers
  are equal, this variable is~1, else~0\\
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

\LTXtable{\linewidth}{\jobname-table-parameters}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]