# Indent second line in table

Tags: tables, indentation

This code create the table printed below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

% outline different types table
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXl}
    \toprule
    Type & Example & Reference \\
    \midrule
    Habitat & Three tree-climbing species used different parts of trees & \textcite{LaraEtAl2015} \\
    Diet & Three species of dabbling ducks \textit{Anas} foraged on seeds of different size and mass & \textcite{BrochetEtAl2012} \\
    Temporal & Different species of \textit{Gyps} vulture visited carcasses at different times of day & \textcite{Kendall2014} \\
    Spatial & Different species of \textit{Sterna} tern foraged in different parts of the sea & \textcite{RobertsonEtAl2014} \\
    Acoustic & A large community of vocalising rainforest species partitioned the sound environment & \textcite{Luther2009} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption[Types of niche partitioning]{Different types of niche partitioning with examples. Note that these types of niche partitioning are not mutually exclusive. For example, two species could partition habitat, which might be a consequence of partitioning diet.}.
  \label{table_niche_partitioning}
\end{table}
%%nichepartitioning

\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBaqJ.jpg)

When a line spills over onto the next line, how can I have the line indented, like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1tdr.jpg)

Comment: Check [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252882/76063)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert a paragraph `\hangindent` for the `X`-column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\newcommand{\textcite}[1]{#1}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l>{\hangindent=2em}Xl}
  \toprule
  Type & Example & Reference \\
  \midrule
  Habitat & Three tree-climbing species used different parts of trees & \textcite{LaraEtAl2015} \\
  Diet & Three species of dabbling ducks \textit{Anas} foraged on seeds of different size and mass & \textcite{BrochetEtAl2012} \\
  Temporal & Different species of \textit{Gyps} vulture visited carcasses at different times of day & \textcite{Kendall2014} \\
  Spatial & Different species of \textit{Sterna} tern foraged in different parts of the sea & \textcite{RobertsonEtAl2014} \\
  Acoustic & A large community of vocalising rainforest species partitioned the sound environment & \textcite{Luther2009} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how can I use `\hangindent` for the `X` column when this is my code: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Xl}`? Note `Xl` instead of `lXl`

Comment: @luciano: Use `\begin{tabularx}{>{\hangindent=1em}Xl}`...

Comment: thanks but that code is throwing an error. Do you know why?

Comment: @luciano: Sorry, that should have been `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\hangindent=1em}Xl}` I forgot that [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) requires a length specification before the table preamble/column specification.